# How to fix: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a problem with my python code. The problem is this line:

```
match = re.search(pattern, bytes).start()
```

but i get this error...i hope you can help me.

Comment: what is start() for?

Comment: There's no result from `search` so there's nothing to call `start()` on.  Impossible to debug further without knowing what `pattern` and `bytes` are.  Also, you shouldn't be using `bytes` as a variable name since it's the name of a builtin type.

Comment: There is no match in the string for your regex pattern so `None` is returned not a `Match` object

Answer (score 2):

I think the code should be like the following.

```
match = re.search(pattern, bytes) 
    
if match != None:        
    print("Match at index %s, %s" % (match.start(), match.end()))        
else: 
    print("The regex pattern does not match.")
```

Hope it could help.